# "615" error code from IronSource banner ads

Tags: ads, ironsource

IronSource banner ads getting. **615 - the server response does not contain banner data** is there i am missing something,

check with default testing **ironsource_key** it's working, also checking by adding `IntegrationHelper.validateIntegration(activity);` getting message from Ironsource like **IntegrationHelper: Google Play Services - VERIFIED**

Here is my implementation of IronSource banner ads like.

```
IronSource.init(activity, activity.getString(R.string.ironsource_key), IronSource.AD_UNIT.BANNER);

IronSourceBannerLayout banner = IronSource.createBanner(activity, ISBannerSize.BANNER);
    FrameLayout.LayoutParams layoutParams = new FrameLayout.LayoutParams(FrameLayout.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT,
            FrameLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
    layout.addView(banner, 0, layoutParams);
    IronSource.loadBanner(banner);
    IntegrationHelper.validateIntegration(activity);

banner.setBannerListener(new BannerListener() {
        @Override
        public void onBannerAdLoaded() {
            System.out.println("==== onBannerAdLoaded");
        }

        @Override
        public void onBannerAdLoadFailed(IronSourceError ironSourceError) {
            System.out.println("==== onBannerAdLoadFailed getErrorMessage : " + ironSourceError.getErrorMessage());
            System.out.println("==== onBannerAdLoadFailed getErrorCode : " + ironSourceError.getErrorCode());
        }

        @Override
        public void onBannerAdClicked() {
            System.out.println("==== onBannerAdClicked");
        }

        @Override
        public void onBannerAdScreenPresented() {
            System.out.println("==== onBannerAdScreenPresented");
        }

        @Override
        public void onBannerAdScreenDismissed() {
            System.out.println("==== onBannerAdScreenDismissed");
        }

        @Override
        public void onBannerAdLeftApplication() {
            System.out.println("==== onBannerAdLeftApplication");
        }
    });
```